# Was/is there a caste/subcaste designated to actually kill the animal at animal sacrifices?

Tags: caste-system, animals, sacrifice

An example of a specialized occupation in Tamil Nadu is the inherited, highly stigmatized office of funeral drummer and graveyard attendant, called vettiyan (drawn from the Paraiyar subcaste).

Is the actual killing of the sacrificed animal considered an act unfit for high castes?

However in this contemporary example, Brahmins seem to have done the killing:

https://www.deccanherald.com/content/544227/brahmins-hold-yaga-sacrifice-goats.html